# To split and arrange number in single inverted

Tags: bash, unix

I have around 65000 products codes in a text file.I wanted to split those number in group of 999 each .Then-after want each 999 number with single quotes separated by comma.

Could you please suggest how I can achieve above scenario through Unix script.

```
87453454
65778445
.
.
.
.
```

Till `65000 productscodes`

Need to arrange in below pattern:

```
'87453454','65778445',
```

Comment: You mentioned *inverted*, but inside your example I cannot see anything being inverted. Please edit your question to precisely specify what exactly you want to invert.

Comment: Apologies. I meant single quote.then separated by comma

Comment: No problem, you can [edit] your question (title and text) so that future readers are not confused .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
    ++c == 1 { out = "\047" $0 "\047"; next }
             { out = out ",\047" $0 "\047" }
    c == 999 { print out; c = 0 }
    END { if (c) print out }
' file
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed "
:a
\$bb
N
0~999{
:b
    s/\n/','/g
    s/^/'/
    s/$/'/
    b
}
ba" file
```

Comment: It is showing the output as expected. Thank you all for this update.

Answer (score 0):

With `Perl`:

```
perl -ne '
    sub pq { chomp; print "\x27$_\x27" } pq;
    for (1 .. 998) {
        if (defined($_ = <>)) {
            print ",";
            pq
        }
    }
    print "\n"
' < file
```

Credit for Mauke perl@libera.chat

Comment: obiwan? I think that should be `2..999`

Comment: also, the question seems to want trailing comma on all lines (except possibly  the final one - that's not clear)

Answer (score 0):

If your input file only contains short codes as shown in your example, you could use the following hack:

```
xargs -L 999 bash -c "printf \'%s\', \"\$@\"; echo" . <inputFile >outputFile
```

Alternatively, you can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -Ene"s/(.*)/'\1',/;H" -e{'0~999','$'}'{z;x;s/\n//g;p}' <inputFile >outputFile
```

- `s/(.*)/'\1',/` wraps each line in `'`...`',`
- but does not print it (`-n`)
- instead, `H` appends the modified line to the so called *hold* space; basically a helper variable storing a single string.
  (This also adds a line break as a separator, but we remove that later).
- Every 999 lines (`0~999`) and at the end of the input file (`$`) ...
- ... the *hold* space is then printed and cleared (`z;x;...;p`)
  while deleting all delimiter-linebreaks (`s/\n//g`) mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

`65000` isn't that many lines for `awk` - just do it all in one shot :

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { FS = RS; RS = "^$"; OFS = (_="\47")(",")_
>
>       } gsub(/^|[^0-9]*$/,_, $!(NF = NF))'
> ```

```
'66771756','69562431','22026341','58085790','22563930',
'63801696','24044132','94255986','56451624','46154427'
```

That's for grouping them all in one line. To make 999 ones, try

```
jot -r 50 10000000 99999999 |
```

> ```
> # change "5" to "999" here
> rs -C= 0 5 | 
>   
> mawk 'sub(".*", "\47&\47", $!(NF -= _==$NF ))' FS== OFS='\47,\47'
> ```

```
'36452530','29776340','31198057','36015730','30143632'
'49664844','83535994','86871984','44613227','12309645'
'58002568','31342035','72695499','54546650','21800933'
'38059391','36935562','98323086','91089765','65672096'
'17634208','14009291','39114390','35338398','43676356'
'14973124','19782405','96782582','27689803','27438921'
'79540212','49141859','25714405','42248622','25589123'
'11466085','87022819','65726165','86718075','56989625'
'12900115','82979216','65469187','63769703','86494457'
'26544666','89342693','64603075','26102683','70528492'
```

- `_==$NF` checks whether right most column is empty or not,

—- i.e. whether there's a trailing edge sep that needds to be trimmed